# Getting or changing CSS class property with Javascript using DOM style

Tags: javascript, css, dom

My objective is to change the background color of a columns in a table without addressing each data entry individually by Id or Name. I know there are several ways to do this, and I've tried 3 to be exact, and I'm having problems with each. For the sake of simplicity and clarity, In this question, I'm asking how to successfully do it using the  [element.style.backgroundColor](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp) object in the DOM. Here's my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tester.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tester.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" onClick="testerFunction()">Test</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th class="col1">Column 1 Header</th>
                <th class="col2">Column 2 Header</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">R1 C1</td>
                <td class="col2">R1 C2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1">R2 C1</td>
                <td class="col2">R2 C2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </body>
 </html>
```

My CSS file:

```
.col1{
    background-color:lime;  
}
```

And my Javascript file:

```
function testerFunction() {
    alert (document.getElementsByClassName('.col1').style.backgroundColor);  
}
```

When I run it I get roughly the same error in IE, Firefox, and Chrome:

> cannot read property 'backgroundColor' of Undefined.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the data type returned by the [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName) DOM object. The referenced website says it returns an HTMLcollection. Other places I've found says it returns a "list" of elements. I tried making an array and assigning the result to the array and accessing each element in the array with a loop, but got the same error at the same place. It might be that I just don't know how to handle a, "collection." At any rate, I was expecting, "lime" or the hex or rgb equivalent because that's what I defined in the CSS file. I want to be able to change it with Javascript. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Added arguments to Shylo Hana's Answer to make it more modular

```
function testerFunction() {
    changeColumnColor('col1','blue');
}
function changeColumnColor(column,color) {
    var cols = document.getElementsByClassName(column);
    for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
      cols[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: check out this: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @shylo's answer is correct, getElementsByClassName returns an array, which definitely has no "style" property

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As mentioned by Quynh Nguyen, you don't need the '.' in the className. However - document.getElementsByClassName('col1') will return an array of objects.

This will return an "undefined" value because an array doesn't have a class. You'll still need to loop through the array elements...

```
function changeBGColor() {
  var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('col1');
  for(i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
    cols[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked simply and beautifully. I added some arguments to make it more modular. Made it an edit to the post for formatting.

Answer (score 33):

I think this is not the best way, but in my case other methods did not work.

```
stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0]
stylesheet.insertRule(".have-border { border: 1px solid black;}", 0);
```

Example from https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

Comment: This really helped me a lot. This is really good for what I'm doing and I learned something new. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe better `document.querySelectorAll(".col1")` because `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in IE 8 and `querySelectorAll` does (althought CSS2 selectors only).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add '.' in your class name. This will do

```
document.getElementsByClassName('col1')
```

Additionally, since you haven't define the background color via javascript, you won't able to call it directly. You have to use window.getComputedStyle() or jquery to achieve what you are trying to do above.

Here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/J9LU8/

Comment: Oh, sweet! It doesn't fix my major problem, but thanks! I'll change that and reference classes that way from now on.

Comment: Thanks! jsfiddle and you are both awesome!

Answer (score 3):

Nice. Thank you. Worked For Me.

Not sure why you loaded jQuery though.  It's not used.  Some of us still use dial up modems and satellite with bandwidth limitations.  Less is more betterer.

```
<script>
        function showAnswers(){
          var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('Answer');
          for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
            cols[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lime';
            cols[i].style.width = '50%';
            cols[i].style.borderRadius = '6px';         
            cols[i].style.padding = '10px';
            cols[i].style.border = '1px green solid';
            }
        }
        function hideAnswers(){
          var cols = document.getElementsByClassName('Answer');
          for(i=0; i<cols.length; i++) {
            cols[i].style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
            cols[i].style.width = 'inheret';
            cols[i].style.borderRadius = '0';
            cols[i].style.padding = '0';
            cols[i].style.border = 'none';          
          }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

very useful to change colors to tab buttons according to the one that is pressed. I integrated with  `this` word

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
        
        
<button class='btn btn-secondary' onclick='myFunction2(this,"red");openCity("Rome")' style="background-color: red;"><strong>ROME</strong></button> 
<button class='btn btn-secondary' onclick='myFunction2(this,"red");openCity("Berlin")'><strong>BERLIN</strong></button>
    
<div id='Rome' class='city' >Welcome to Rome</div>
<div id='Berlin' class='city' >Welcome to Berlin</div>
        
     <script>   
        function openCity(cityName) {
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName('city');
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
              x[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
            document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = 'block';
          }
        
          function myFunction2(elmnt,clr) {
          var classes = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-secondary');
          for(i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            classes[i].style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
          }
          elmnt.style.backgroundColor = clr;
          }
        </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

**If you are looking for sending color data from backend**

```
def color():
    color = "#{:06x}".format(random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
    return color
```