# Add a style to a class onclick a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these 3 Boxes with the same classes and a button:

```js
function turnRedAndAddPadding() {
  /* ??? */
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="turnRedAndAddPadding();">Press</button>

<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
```

I want to add styles to the class `.box` when clicking on the button without adding a new class to the boxes. Basically, if you press the button, the class `.box` should get a red background color and a padding and all the elements that have this class should have the same. Is there an easy way in JavaScript to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you searched about adding styles with javascript?

Comment: @Sfili_81 yeah, of course! Normally I used to add Inline styles per JavaScript but it's not the cleanest way to code, so I needed this solution.

Comment: with javascript you can toggle class to the element, maybe this can be a better and cleaner solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to add properties to the *existing* class. What you should do is add a *new* class that contains those red/padding properties to each element's class *list*.

Toolkit

1. You need some way to "pick up" the elements for processing. Since you have more than one [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is probably the go-to choice which will give you a static nodelist (rather than a live HTML collection that methods like `getElementsByClassName` give you which have some side-effects if you don't use them correctly.)
2. You'll want a way to [iterate over the elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) to the processing. There are a number of possibilities provided in that link but [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is a good choice here.
3. You'll want a way to update the class list of each element in the iteration. The unsuprisingly-named [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) has, among its methods, [`add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) which accepts a string of the CSS class you want to add.
4. Define a new class ("redpad" in this example) that can be used.
5. Finally, because you want to avoid inline JS in 2023, you should be using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) which accepts a) an event type and b) the name of the function you want to call when that event is fired.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

button.addEventListener('click', turnRedAndAddPadding);

function turnRedAndAddPadding() {
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    box.classList.add('redpad');
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline;
}

.redpad {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Press</button>

<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your answer. This is a pretty interesting way to this problem but why did you say "You don't really want to add properties to the existing class.". Isn't it possible? Because that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: It's not needed and you're just adding more complication to the code/logic. Adding a new class to the list with just those properties is easy. What if you added to the existing class instead? If you wanted to remove those properties - again complicated, but with `classlist` you just `remove` the class from the list that you want. There's also `toggle` if you need it. @GucciBananaKing99. Also, this is the standard way of adding class information these days.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353331/getting-or-changing-css-class-property-with-javascript-using-dom-style) you could try something like this:

```js
function turnRedAndAddPadding() {
  stylesheet = document.styleSheets[0]
  stylesheet.insertRule(".box { background-color: red; padding: 10px;}", 0);
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="turnRedAndAddPadding();">Press</button>

<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thanos, thank you for your answer. This is a pretty interesting way to solve this problem. I will look at the other answers and eventually give the check. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some really useful documentation by W3 Schools talks about how to use `getElementsByClassName` which you can find [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) You can find about editing the padding as well from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_padding.asp) via the padding property of each element.

Below I am finding all div's that have the class box. Then iterating over each of them and assigning the colour and padding. You can change this to your liking.

There are also [many other properties](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp) that you can edit for each DOM element like divs!

```
function turnRedAndAddPadding() {
  const collection = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

  for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    collection[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    collection[i].style.padding = '5px';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately I have to add the styles to the class and not to the elements. Thank you so much though, thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some javascript you can achieve your goal.

`document.querySelectorAll` with this you can collect all elements with class `box` and then loop with a foreach function

```js
function turnRedAndAddPadding() {
  let box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
  box.forEach(el => {
    el.style.background = 'red';
    el.style.padding = '20px'
  })
}
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="turnRedAndAddPadding()">Press</button>

<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sfili_81, thank you for your answer. The problem is that of course I know the way to add Inline styles to an element but as I mentioned in the comment above, I have to add the styles to the class and not to the element. But thank you

Comment: Your welcome. I've read your comment after my answer